# While saving shapefile to disk, is there a way to set the geometry type and SHPT

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, geometry

QGIS 3.0.1

I wrote a code to create a vector layer and save it to disk as shapefile .
Is there a way I can save its geometry property as 'Point' and SHPT as 'Point'

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.0", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False) ###
qgs.initQgis() ###

_layer1 = QgsVectorLayer("C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/MasterLine.shp", "MASTERLINE", "ogr")

if not _layer1.isValid():
  print("Layer failed to load!")

else:
    print("Layer was loaded successfully!")

_writer1 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(_layer1,"C:/Arundhati/Automation Test Script/Radio Signal/MasterLine12.shp",'utf-8',QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(),'ESRI Shapefile')

qgs.exitQgis()
```

please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a2e784d89a125182df55b45b3ffccabbf), you can set the WkbType upon `QgsVectorFileWriter` instatiation, Here's an example:

```
from qgis.core import QgsWKBTypes

# Creates the file using giving settings
vector_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("path/to/your/file", 'utf-8', _layer1.fields(), QgsWKBTypes.Point, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326L))

# Add your features to the created Shapefile
for _feature in features:
    vector_writer.addFeature(_feature)

# Close the writer to avoid concurrency
del vector_writer
```

Following this method, you do not need to use `writeAsVectorFormat()`, The file will be created during instantiation

Comment: I am getting following error :-  NameError: name 'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined. What could be the reason? Is this version specific?          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 42, in <module>
NameError: name 'QgsWKBTypes' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I fix the code to `import QgsWKBTypes`, instead of `QgsWkbTypes`

Comment: Umm No. It now gives me import error:- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QgsWKBTypes'

Comment: I think it is not a version problem, as QGis 3.0 seems to use `QgsWKBTypes`. I just notice you've used `from qgis.core import *`, since you have this, try removing `from qgis.core import QgsWKBTypes`

Comment: Hmm. Ok. Still the same import error. I am trying to find a solution for similar problems but no luck

Comment: As a workaround, try changing `QgsWKBTypes.Point` to `1`, since QgsWKBTypes is only an Enum, you should be fine using `1` for Point and removing the import statement

Comment: Uhh. It worked but now its giving me trouble for the features as it is not defined anywhere. So added a like features = _layer1.addFeatures(). But it crashes QGIS.

Comment: change to `for feature in _layer1.getFeatures()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77582/discussion-between-jay-and-xldias).

Comment: Is there any other way than QgsVectorFileWriter?

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: sorry for the delay, it should be possible to do this via shapely, but I've never done this, I am in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77582/discussion-between-jay-and-xldias) now